# I'm getting this error: "Missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    CUSTOMER_NO INT(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
    CUSTOMER_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(200),
    CUSTOMER_PHONE INT(10),
    GENDER VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

Error

> Missing right parenthesis

Comment: Then you should at least provide the description of what you have tried to resolve the issue and why it didn't help.

Comment: And in most of the programming languages and databases `int` has no size property and either depends on platform or has fixed size of 4 byte. For other sizes there are appropriate `tiny-`, `small-` or `big-` prefixes. What an `int(3)` is expected to be is very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, the `INT` type is not parameterizable. `INT` is an alias for `NUMBER(38)`.

Either remove the parameters (ie `INT(3)` and `INT(10)` should be just `INT`):

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
  CUSTOMER_NO INT PRIMARY KEY,
  CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
  CUSTOMER_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(200),
  CUSTOMER_PHONE INT,
  GENDER VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

*or*, if you want to limit the number of digits, use `NUMBER(p)`:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
  CUSTOMER_NO NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
  CUSTOMER_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(200),
  CUSTOMER_PHONE NUMBER(10),
  GENDER VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

Comment: The second sentence is wrong. `INT` is an [ANSI data type that, in Oracle, is an alias](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF) for `NUMBER(38)`.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks. Corrected. (I stumbled onto the wrong doc).